# Extract mean color from borders of convex image mask

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

My segmentation model generate some mask for image. This mask is always convex (I use cv2.convexhull). My goal is to extract mean color from "borders" of my mask.
In future I will crop mask from image just by min/max x/y coords and fill empty space dynamically, based on this border color.

Below is example, where I filled everything with black color, extracted from borders color should be ~gray

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the code you used to achieve this image?  This way for those who suggest answers, we can work with your code.

Comment: If you are able to extract image you posted, then all you need to do is run findContours again with the CHAIN_APPROX_NONE flag. The outermost contour has all the points of contour for you two take the mean value of.

Answer (score 1):

The following idea will work on all kind of shapes (not only convex)- do erosion (e.g.: `cv2.imerode`) with a kernel of your choosing on the binary (mask) version of your image, and then subtract this eroded mask from the actual mask to get a mask of the border. now you can do what you want to the data of the border.